# Pandas creating a column based on condition

Tags: python, pandas

[image]

So what I want to do is to add a new column called `'Top Tier'` where the MAKEs `'BMW, FORD, BENZ, CHEVROLET'` will have the value `'Top'` and the other MAKEs will have `'Not Top'`

```
df['Top Tier'] = np.where(df['MAKE']==['FORD', 'BMW', 'BENZ' , 'CHEVROLET], 'Top', 'Not Top')
```

^This doesn't work. I want to do this using np.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution using `np` as requested by the OP:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({"MAKE": ['FORD', 'BMW', 'BENZ' , 'CHEVROLET', "SOMETHING ELSE"]})
top_tiers = ["FORD", "BMW", "BENZ" , "CHEVROLET"]
df["Top Tier"] = np.where(df['MAKE'].map(lambda x: x in top_tiers), "Top", "Not Top")
df
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way:

```py
df['Top Tier'] = df['MAKE'].map(lambda x: 'Top' if x in ['FORD','BMW','BENZ','CHEVROLET'] else 'Not Top')
```

Or this:

```py
df['Top Tier'] = df['MAKE'].isin(['FORD','BMW','BENZ','CHEVROLET']).replace({True: 'Top', False: 'Not Top'})
```